# Is there an Ajax call generator from webapi

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a web api c# code, i.e:

```
public void Post([FromBody]List<ImageModel> images,string id)
{
```

where ImageModel is:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    public bool isApproved { get; set; }

    public [another object...] cropped { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm looking for a tool that will generate ajax call example given code like the above or any other webapi code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create help pages for your api methods.

Follow below steps to adding Help pages in your web api application:

From the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager, and then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager Console window, type one of the following commands:

```
For a C# application: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage
For a Visual Basic application: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage.VB
```

Also, make sure to register areas. In the Global.asax file, add the following code to the Application_Start method, if it is not there already:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Add this code, if not present.
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
}
```

Adding API Documentation:
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));

To Add simple test client to ASP.NET Web API Help Page follow below steps:

Step 1: Install the Test Client package
Install the WebApiTestClient package from the NuGet Package Manager. Make sure to “Include Prerelease” then just type in “WebApiTestClient” and click Install.

Step 2: Wire up the Test Client on Help Page
Open the file Api.cshtml (under Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help) and add the following:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel("TestClientDialogs")
@Html.DisplayForModel("TestClientReferences")
```

Now run the application and test the api using ajax call with the help of test client.

For that refer [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)

After that [Adding a simple Test Client to ASP.NET Web API Help Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/02/adding-a-simple-test-client-to-asp-net-web-api-help-page.aspx)

This will give test client to test your api's using ajax requests.

Please let me know, is this works for you.